# Black dust and crackling sound on rear rim

Tags: wheels

Pls I noticed black dust on one of car rear rim and a crackling sound on the same side what are the cause and what should be done? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven’t added much information to go on, I am going to go out on a limb.

I presume that the crackling sound is heard just after you have been on a journey in the vehicle.

What these symptoms would suggest to me is that the brake on that wheel is seizing on.  This means that you are driving around with the brake on, which will cause the brake to become very hot.  The crackling sound will be the sound of the brake cooling down and contracting.

The black dust will be due to the excessive brake lining wear at that wheel.

After driving carefully feel for a difference in heat at each wheel.  Be carful not to burn yourself because the wheel could have become very hot.

If this is the issue, then the brake mechanism will need to be investigated to identify why it is seizing on.  If this was happening on the front wheel, you would also likely have a symptom of the vehicle pulling to the side of the faulty brake, but this isn’t as noticeable with a fault on the rear.